# How can I move the login behaviour from the /login URL to my home page in a Laravel application?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am pretty new in **PHP** and moreover in **Laravel** framework (I came from **Java**) and I have the following problem related to **Laravel** security.

I have correctly configured my Laravel login system so if I access to the page:

```
http://localhost:8000/login
```

I obtain my login page from where I can access to the restriced area of my portal. This is the standard Laravel login page.

My doubt is: can I take this behavior into my home page? Because I have to put the login into a custom login from into my home page (the one that is automatically opened launching **http://localhost:8000/**).

How can I do this?

Comment: You want to put the /login functionality on / i.e. on root ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware

Comment: Are you saying you just need a HTML log in form on your home page? If so just copy the HTML from `login.blade.php` and customize as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question i understand that:

`You are adding the login form in the homepage and not trying to provide the link to the login page from homepage.`

If this is not your question i could delete my answer.

So, if you are using `blade` you could easily import the chunks of codes from login page.

More on Sub-view Here:

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#including-sub-views

Example:

**login.blade.php**

```
<div class="form">
    //your login form contents
</div>
```

**homepage.blade.php**

```
//your homepage codes

@include('login')

//rest of your homepage codes
```

Note:

The path to your `subview` is relative to `resources/views/`.

i.e.  If you have this folder structure like this:

```
|-resources
   |-views
      |-homepage.blade.php
      |-partials
          |-login.blade.php
```

then you will need to use:

```
@include('partials.login')
```

in your `homepage.blade.php` to use that view.

Comment: Exactly I have to add the login form to my home page. The problem is slightly different. I just have an home page that contains a login form (but is not the Laravel standard one). My doubt is: can I adapt this form to act as the Laravel standard one? I want mantain my CSS style but I want that it acts like the Laravel login form. Can I simply change the submit URL and insert the blade check for error taking it from the Laravel login form?

Comment: @AndreaNobili Yes! you could do that you could use everything custom made and use the different submit URL for your form. You could just give the dynamic `submit Url` that could be inserted into your login form.

Answer (score 0):

Inside web.php add this route at the end of the routes

```
Route::get('/', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update routes file in laravel like below.

Basically your routes file is located in

`YourProject/app/Http/routes.php`

here you can copy the View(blade) / Controller of `/login` route to `/`. Like example shown below.

```
Route::get('/login',function() {
   return view('login');
});
```

Replace the above one to

```
Route::get('/',function() {
   return view('login');
});
```

example above is without controller.

Hope it works!!